# SESSION ou COOKIE em Loja Virtual

Tags: php

Estou em um projeto de uma loja virtual, porém estou com o seguinte dilema. Um determinado usuário acessa a loja e coloca um produto no carrinho. As compras estou armazenando em uma tabela do BD, pois fica mais fácil de ter um controle de abandono de carrinho/desistência, porém os dados do usuário estou armazenando da seguinte forma:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["SESSIONID"])){
  $dataHora = date("Y-m-d H:i");
  $sessionID = md5($ip.$dataHora);
  $_SESSION["SESSIONID"] = $sessionID;
}else{
  $sessionID = $_SESSION["SESSIONID"];
}
```

Coloquei a data e hora após o IP caso o usuário esteja acessando de uma rede, como por exemplo rede de trabalho, dessa forma caso um outro usuário acesse a loja por essa rede, não verá a compra do outro usuário de um outro computador (corrijam-me se eu estiver errado).

Mas e se o usuário fechar o browser sem finalizar a compra? Ao retornar, o carrinho estará vazio. Pensei em armazenar em Cookie, mas e se o browser não estiver aceitando Cookies? Existe algum outro meio?

Comment: Acho que dessa forma, apenas colocando a data e a hora, vc não irá conseguir diferenciar uma máquina da outra num mesmo IP. Em relação aos cookies, sugiro forçar o usuário a aceitar o uso de cookies (verificar se o navegador está aceitando. Caso contrário, emitir uma mensagem orientando a habilitar)... ou então usar localStorage...

Comment: Olá DvD. Na verdade diferencia, pois a estrutura é IP + Data + Hora + Minuto. Sobre o localStorage não teria a mesma funcionalidade do Cookie e dependendo do navegador teria um limite de tamanho? Confesso que nunca usei o localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Porque você não utiliza o banco e cookies ou session?

Utilizando o banco você é capaz de saber se o usuário abandonou o carrinho hoje as 14:34 ou se abandonou a 456 dias atrás.

Ter controle sobre abandono de carrinho é muito importante para alcançar vendas em potencial independente do tempo em que o carrinho foi montado. Deixar essas importantes informações na mão do usuário não é bom, nem praticável, qualquer *ctrl-f5* no navegador e você perde todas as informações e consequentemente dados. Dado é dinheiro, simples assim.

Crie uma verificação que procura os dados nos cookies, se existir não precisa gastar conexão com o banco. Se não existir vai la e recupera esses dados no banco.

Sempre associe o carrinho ao id do usuário. Crie a tabela usuário e a tabela carrinho contendo uma chave estrangeira com id do usuário, dessa forma não interessa se o camarada acessa da mesma rede ou de plutão, o carrinho dele sempre será dele.

Comment: Olá Bsalvo. Exatamente. Na verdade estou seguindo os seguintes passos: O cliente escolhe o produto e clica para visualizar a descrição. Após clicar  em comprar, é salvo em uma tabela do BD, onde é construído o carrinho dele e quando clica em finalizar, ele é levado para o checkout onde após se logar/cadastrar faço o update na tabela do carrinho com o ID do cadastro de usuário. No gerenciador da loja tenho um gráfico onde mostra o abandono após e antes de se logar. O abandono após do checkout, fica mais fácil enviar por exemplo que o produto está esperando para fechar compras ou até mesmo...

Comment: ... na visualização no Painel do Cliente. A minha dúvida é quando o usuário não passa pelo checkout e as compras são abandonadas. Como faria para que ele ao acessar, as compras ficassem no carrinho, porém esbarrei no problema do Cookie, quando o browser nao tem habilitado.

Answer (score -2):

Cookies não suporta tanto, e session, não é bem pra isso .
Experimentei e tenho usado o HTML5 Localstorage para esse tipo de coisa. Este é uma espécie de API de cachê local, que mantem os dados, não é só se fechar o navegador. Ele mantem os dados persistentemente ainda que o chrome seja finalizado no Gerenciador de tarefas, e em seguida tenha resetado o computador 10 vezes. Desligadas as placas e fontes, etc. Desconectado da internet (por isso o session não rola), e ainda pode suportar milhares de vezes mais informações que seria possível com Cookies. Se tiver carregado o conteúdo da página para navegação offline, ele tambem vai continuar recuperando os dados offline. para um calculador de orçamento, por exemplo.

E por aí vai ... HTML5 LOCAL STORAGE .